# How can I select the final account when I am doing a merge of two accounts?

Tags: support, accounts, merge-accounts

Hello I am trying to merge two accounts, and when I fill the form and validate the emails for merging the accounts, I always get the following message

The account A will be remover ...

But I want to remove the account B, and transfer all data to the account A, how can I select the final account for the merge?

I started the process from both accounts, but always the account A is the final account.

Comment: An option doesn't exist for this... Account merges *always* go to the account with the *lowest* user id...

Comment: can some data loss in the process?

Comment: What data loss are you concerned about?

Comment: For example, some badges, or some questions in another stack accounts, or for exampl I have 30 post edit, and I only need 50 more for get the badge, that data

Comment: You'll end up with one account that's got all activity from both accounts... So if you had 20 suggested edits on one and 30 on the other - after the merge, the older account will have 50 suggested edits for instance... Same with badges and question and answers, reviews, flags etc...

Comment: I just do it, and in StackOverflow I lost 3 silver badges, is normal? this need one day for update all accounts?

Comment: Badges get awarded periodically... so if the combined account fulfils the criteria for that badge - it'll come back shortly... Just give it some time and don't worry about it :)

Comment: Almost all badges are automatic re-rewarded. The only exceptions are badges that were awarded for some criteria that you no longer satisfy, such as if your a post was downvoted from 10 to 9 so you no longer get a good question badge for it.